# 3.64 slow or won't preview hair curves in render mode

Tags: hair

I was having good success with hair curves in Blender 3.6. No problems. I have an NVIDIA RTX A6000 GPU and was using Cycles Hair and GPU computation.

I upgraded to 3.64 and now am having all kinds of problems. Worst is instead of the fast previews in render mode I was getting, I'm now getting extremely slow or no preview at all.

Please help.

OK... apologies. I tweaked my GPU settings and am good to go. I don't know why I needed to do that since it was working great earlier. But it's fixed now :)